# html and js help needed.. strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page 
http://www.maryveale.com/sculpture/index.html
that loads a js at /media/js/bill-studio.js
that causes the following problem.

When the web page is loaded there are some images shown.
Clicking on the first image should open the page /sculpture/1986/index.html

and it does if you right click open in new window, however, by clicking on it it doesn't.
There is something in the js that stops the click working.

Can anyone help me remove it!

Thanks a gabillion!
Bill

Comment: It doesn't work in my Firefox.

Comment: it doesn't work in my firefox either

Comment: it does work in firefox but i had to remove the index.html first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's probably this line:

```
studio.show_image(a)}return false});
```

or if not, it's one of those `return false` lines you've got in your script. Have a little play with removing the return statements and see what happens, and you might get a better idea of how your script is working.

Comment: excellent!! thanks a million Skilldrick!!! I passed about 2hours on that and you got it in a minute or so!!

Comment: @Skilldrick How did you spot it?

Comment: First I did a search in the .js for "preventDefault", then for "return false". I knew it had to be one of those two.

Comment: Btw, even though you're reducing the number of requests by putting all your JS in one file, you're missing out on the benefits of the cache. Take out the JQuery from your js file and link to this instead:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: There are a number or return false statements in it. How can one drill down to the anchor's event handler?

Comment: There were only a few in the non-jQuery part though. I knew that it wouldn't be in there. I saw that the selector included "a", so it had to be that...

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving out the slash preceding each directory name in the .

Just a thought on first glance, unless you've tried that already.

Comment: That would send the user to the wrong page (probably a 404) rather than prevent the click from doing anything at all.